# what is the difference between @PreAuthorize and @PostAuthorize in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

What is the purpose of two different authorize method as conditions need to be evaluated before accessing any data?

Answer (score 5):

**@PreAuthorize:**

The `@PreAuthorize` as name suggest can check for authorization before entering into method. The `@PreAuthorize` authorizes on the basis of role or the argument which is passed to the method.

- Based on role or the argument which is passed to the method

**@PostAuthorize:**

The `@PostAuthorize` as name suggest checks for authorization after method execution. The `@PostAuthorize` authorizes on the basis of logged in roles, return object by method and passed argument to the method. For the returned object spring security provides built-in keyword i.e. returnObject.

- Based in logged in roles, return object by method and passed argument to the method